# Extract data from a web table with selenium and compare it to a JSON response

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am driving tests with selenium grid and I need to extract search results from a web table and insert it into a java table or list in order to compare it to a JSON response :

Here is the form of my JSON response :

```
{
    "facets": 
    {
        "application": 
        [
            {
                "name": "38",
                "distribution": 1
            }
        ],
        "node": 
        [
            {
                "name": "frstlwardu03_05",
                "distribution": 1
            }
        ],
        "area": 
        [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "distribution": 1
            }
        ],
        "company": 
        [
            {
                "name": "war001",
                "distribution": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "duObjects": 
    [
        {
            "id": "TASK|TSK(ZRM760J)(000)(ZRM760JU00)(000)|ZSRPSRM000",
            "name": "TSK(ZRM760J)(000)(ZRM760JU00)(000)",
            "mu": "ZSRPSRM000",
            "label": "",
            "session": "ZRM760J|000",
            "sessionLabel": "SAP SRM Achats frais generaux execution",
            "uprocHeader": "ZRM760JU00|000",
            "uprocHeaderLabel": "Header for SRM760J",
            "uprocHeaderType": "CL_INT",
            "domain": "M",
            "domainLabel": "",
            "application": "38",
            "applicationLabel": "magasin",
            "highlightResult": 
            {
                "name": "name",
                "word": "TSK"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageCurrent": 1,
    "pageNb": 1
}
```

And here us what I am getting from the web site:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="#/en/object/TASK|TSK(IAM720JUA5)(000)|BIST_CE891">
                <p style="font-size:11px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="#/en/object/TASK|TSK(ITP191HF10)(000)|RITP_BDDH1">
                <p style="font-size:11px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is extract the duobject name value from the json object or array and compare it to the value in the HTML table.

So far this is the code I have written but I am kind of blocked on how to iterate through that json object and the html table and compare results :

This code will read the API URL and extract the json duObjects name

```
public static String  getresults (String URL) throws IOException, JSONException
{
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(URL);
    return json.getJSONArray("duObjects").getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
}
```

This code will drive selenium to enter search keyword in the web page ans search usinf the same API used for json request :

```
driver.get(TestURL);
WebElement input1 =        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[1]"));          
input1.sendKeys("guest");        
WebElement input2 =     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/input[2]"));          
input2.sendKeys("guest");
WebElement btn =   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/button"));
btn.click();
WebElement w1 =   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/header/nav/div[1]/form/div/input"));
w1.sendKeys( "tsk");
WebElement w2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]"));
w2.click();
```

I would like to use this code to check the consistency of my front end results with my JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar doubt.
I want do compare a JSON with an native app on my automation using Appium.

I need to verify if the structure of the app agrees with the JSON.